# Method Not Allowed: /music/add/ "POST" Error 405 for Django rest Framework

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework, django-views, http-status-code-405

I am creating a spotify like backend and I am trying to create a track
So it would take a POST request
I tried bunch of different approaches through stack overflow and any resource I could get to.

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/add/
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: token 3e356c812614c3d4344e0d06773c27387b1e4c12

{
  "title": "Evil Ways", 
  "duration": "00:03:47", 
  "release_date": "2023-09-03", 
  "audio_file": "/media/tracks/Music_Library.musiclibrary.zip", 
  "artist": 2, 
  "album": 2, 
  "genre": 1
}
```

I am sending the request through a .rest file and I get the response

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Thu, 08 Feb 2024 09:11:56 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.9.0
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept, Cookie
Allow: OPTIONS, GET
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 41

{
  "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."
}
```

the end point  is in music app's urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # path for get requests
    path('',views.get_all_tracks, name='get_all_tracks'),
    path('<str:track_name>/', views.get_tracks_by_name, name='get_tracks_by_name'),
    path('add/', views.add_track),
    

]
```

my django app's urls file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import (
    home_page,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_page),
    
    path('auth/', include('authentication.urls')),
    path('music/', include('music.urls')),
    path('album/', include('album.urls')),
    path('artist/', include('artist.urls')),
    path('playlist/', include('playlist.urls'))
]
```

In my views.py file I have

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

from .models import Track, Artist, Genre, Album
from .serializers import TrackSerializer

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes , permission_classes
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

# ... other views


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def add_track(request): 
    if request.method =="POST":
        title = request.data.get('title')
        artist_id = request.data.get('artist')
        album_id = request.data.get('album')
        duration = request.data.get('duration')
        release_date = request.data.get('release_date')
        genre_id = request.data.get('genre')
        audio_file = request.data.get('audio_file')

            # Create a new Track object
        track = Track.objects.create(
            title=title,
            artist_id=artist_id,
            album_id=album_id,
            duration=duration,
            release_date=release_date,
            genre_id=genre_id,
            audio_file=audio_file
        )

            # Return a JSON response with the created track data
        data = {
                'title': track.title,
                'artist': track.artist.name,
                'album': track.album.title,
                'duration': str(track.duration),
                'release_date': str(track.release_date),
                'genre': track.genre.name,
                'audio_file': track.audio_file.url,  # Assuming 'audio_file' is a FileField
            }
        return JsonResponse(data, status=201)
    else:
        return "this page needs a POST request"
```

the models file looks like this

```
from django.db import models
from artist.models import Artist
from album.models import Album

class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Track(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    duration = models.DurationField()
    release_date = models.DateField()
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='tracks/')
    # Add other track-related fields (e.g., lyrics)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I have a serializer file but I'll keep it out for now.
I have been beating my head against the wall for 2 days so any help is appreciated

I am trying to create a new Track and get a Status 201 from the server
I need to atleast the server not to return me error 405 so that I can go ahead and complete the POST requests and adding data.

Comment: I am assuming `urls.py` you have shared is app urls. can you share your project `urls.py`

Comment: ```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import (
    home_page,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_page),
    
    path('auth/', include('authentication.urls')),
    path('music/', include('music.urls')),
    path('album/', include('album.urls')),
    path('artist/', include('artist.urls')),
    path('playlist/', include('playlist.urls'))
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try registering **path('', home_page)** to the last of your urlpatterns list after **path('playlist/', include('playlist.urls'))**. If it still doesn't work then please share all other paths registered in the music app's urls.py and also share all other views of the views.py

Comment: Thank you for your answer
turns out I am a dummy,
in my track app
I have <str> before add url which means all strings go to lookup before it can go to post url
Feel like a dummy!
Your help is much appreciated guys!!!!

Answer (score 0):

in music app url I have

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # path for get requests
    path('',views.get_all_tracks, name='get_all_tracks'),
    path('<str:track_name>/', views.get_tracks_by_name, name='get_tracks_by_name'),
    path('add/', views.add_track),
    

]
```

instead it should be

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # path for get requests
    path('',views.get_all_tracks, name='get_all_tracks'),
# your add should come before it goes to the next URL in this list
    path('add/', views.add_track),
    # if the path below comes first no track will get past it as it is a string :-)
    path('<str:track_name>/', views.get_tracks_by_name, name='get_tracks_by_name'),

    

]
```